# Get time difference between two timespan in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I have two variables :

```
Dim starttime As TimeSpan
Dim endtime As TimeSpan
```

My starttime value is : 02:30:00 (I mean 2.30AM)
 2.30AM is next day

My endTime Value is   : 10:30:00(I mean 10.30Am)

I want to get time difference of these. So I have code like this:

```
Dim span3 As TimeSpan = starttime .Subtract(endtime )
```

Now I am getting span3 : 08:00:00

This is wrong answer. Actually I want to get 16:00:00. (this is the exact differnce between 2.30Am To 10.30 Am)

How I can calculate this?

Comment: well it's not wrong, exact difference in *same day* is 9 hours, is that 02:00 AM from the next day ?

Comment: The answer is correct as you are subtracting timespans which means hours and minutes ... For your purpose you have to use DateTime.

Comment: so..how i can do..i want to get 15:00:00

Comment: From 2AM to 11AM, the difference is 15hours?

Comment: @Nadeem_MK He's probably looking for the difference from 11AM to 2AM the next day.

Comment: Your End TimeSpan had to have 1 day and 02:00:00 hours, and then you will have to subtract 0 days and 11:00:00 hours, it that what you are after ? Remember end time is greater than start time so you must use endTime.Subtract

Comment: yes you are correct..so how i can calculate that

Comment: @user2786971 Please update your question, your start time is 11:00 AM and end time is 02:00 AM NEXT day.

Comment: @user2786971 how can your start time can be AFTER end time ?

Comment: sir my start time is 02:30:00am of next day and end time is 11:30:00 Am of the current day..in my project i have one senariyo like that..thats why.

Comment: You _can't use a `Timespan`_ variable to hold your starttime and endtime.  You need to use a `DateTime` variable, since a `Timespan` cannot hold a time, only a duration.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to use a DateTime variable to hold your start time and end time.  Like this:

```
Dim startTime As New DateTime(2013, 9, 19, 10, 30, 0)     ' 10:30 AM today
Dim endTime As New DateTime(2013, 9, 20, 2, 0, 0)     ' 2:00 AM tomorrow

Dim duration As TimeSpan = endTime - startTime        'Subtract start time from end time

Console.WriteLine(duration)
```

Result:

15:30:00

UPDATE:

To convert that result to minutes, you can use the TotalMinutes property of the TimeSpan variable:

```
Console.WriteLine(duration.TotalMinutes)
```

Result:

930

Comment: @user2786971 - Does that represent a _time_ or does it represent a _length_ of time?  If it is a length of time, you can use a TimeSpan.  See my updated answer.

Answer (score 3):

You're confusing `DateTime` and `TimeSpan`. `TimeSpan` stores a duration, therefore anything about AM and PM is not relevant. If you want to compare two times, you should use `DateTime` and subtract them both, which will give you a `TimeSpan`.

You cannot give a TimeSpan a value of '2am', you you should use `DateTime` for that.

Consider:

```
var date1 = DateTime.Now.Date.AddHours(2); // pseudo code 2am
var date2 = DateTime.Now.Date.AddHours(11); // pseudo code 11am

var result = date2 - date1;
```

The result here is going to be a duration of 9 hours.

If you want it to be 2am the following day, you should include AddDays(1);

```
var date1 = DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(1).AddHours(2); // pseudo code 2am the next day
var date2 = DateTime.Now.Date.AddHours(11); // pseudo code 11am

var result = date1 - date2;
```

The result here is going to be 15 hours.

Comment: instead of adding addhours(2) i can pass addhours(myvariable)..may be my time 02:30:30

Comment: You could use some combination of `AddDays` `AddHours` `AddMinutes` but it is not clear what you are trying to do. If you explain what you are trying to achieve with this code it may help. It might be as simple of doing `timespan1 - timespan2` instead of `timespan2 - timespan1`, or `24 - theResult`.

Comment: from starttime i try to retrive hour like this:Dim hour As TimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromHours(starttime)  but this time showing error

Comment: @user2786971 - You cannot store a _time_ in a Timespan variable.  As SLC indicated it does not store times, it stores _intervals_.  If you wish to store a time, use a `DateTime` variable.

Answer (score 1):

HERE IS MY SOLUTION FOR DIFFERENCE IN HOURS

```
        'WORKS ONLY TIME SPAN WITHIN 48 HRS
        Dim HRS As TimeSpan
        Dim St As TimeSpan = TimeSpan.Parse(L_A_START.Text)
        Dim Cl As TimeSpan = TimeSpan.Parse(L_A_CLOSE.Text)

        HRS = Cl - St

        If HRS.Hours <= 0 Then
            HRS = (HRS + New TimeSpan(0, 24, 0, 0, 0))
        End If

        L_A_HRS.Text = HRS.ToString()
```