# get each value from timspan variable to integer variable in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

i have one timespan varaible like this:

```
dim startime as timespan
```

my starttime value is :11:30:15 (i mean 11Hr.30mnt,15 second).
how i can fetch each value to different variable..i mean

```
dim hr as integer  
dim mnt as integer 
dim sec as integer
```

i want to get hr=11 ,mnt=30,sec=15
i tryed somthing like this:

```
Dim hour As integer = TimeSpan.FromHours(starttime)
```

but this time showing error:

> value type'System.timespan'cannot be converted to 'Double'

Comment: You are still confusing TimeSpan and DateTime, like you did in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18895045/get-time-difference-between-two-timespan-in-vb-net). Let me ask you the following: If you timespan starts at 11:30:15, **when does it end**? Am TimeSpan has a start **and an end**. What you want is a DateTime, a single point in time.

Comment: now i got it sir..but i have one more doubt.. Dim result As TimeSpan my result variable holding value 14:15:15(mean 14hr:15mnt:15 sec) .i want to convert this to minutes..

Comment: thanks sir...i got it exact out put

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Dim startTime As New TimeSpan(11, 30, 15)
Dim hours As Integer = startTime.Hours
Dim mnt as Integer = startTime.Minutes
Dim sec as Integer = startTime.Seconds
Dim allMinutes as Double = startTime.TotalMinutes
```

Comment: sir..but i have one more doubt..i declared my varibale like this Dim result As TimeSpan my result variable holding value 14:15:15(mean 14hr:15mnt:15 sec) .i want to convert this to minutes..how i can do?

Comment: Look at the example again.  startTime.TotalMinutes will contain the timespan value as minutes.