# How to compare two time in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datetime

I have 1 String in VB.net

```
Dim str As String = "2014/08/15 19:45"
```

I have 2 time

```
Dim startDate As String = "6:30"
Dim endDate As String = "22:00"
```

How to compare "str" with "startDate" & "endDate" ?

Comment: convert that to DateTime and then simple subtract will do. You will get TimeSpan as result

Comment: Are you trying to determine if the date represented by str is in between the times represented by startDate and endDate?  I would rename your variables to be more indicative of what the hold - startDate -> startTime and endDate -> endTime.

Comment: Do not store them as string. Store them in a proper DateTime type. Then it'll be easy to compare times.

Comment: Iam newbie in vb.net. You can help me write code. Many thanks

Comment: Check this out: http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?501620-Determine-if-Now-TimeOfDay-Is-Between-Two-Times

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get time difference between two timespan in vb.net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18895045/get-time-difference-between-two-timespan-in-vb-net)

Answer (score 4):

First, you have strings not DateTimes or TimeSpan. But you need both if you want to compare them. So use `Date.Parse`, `Date.ParseExact` (or the `...TryParse` versions to check invalid data):

```
Dim str As String = "2014/08/15 19:45"
Dim dt1 = Date.ParseExact(str, "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)

Dim startDate As String = "6:30"
Dim tsStart = TimeSpan.Parse(startDate)

Dim endDate As String = "22:00"
Dim tsEnd = TimeSpan.Parse(endDate)
```

Now you can compare them:

```
If dt1.TimeOfDay >= tsStart AndAlso dt1.TimeOfDay <= tsEnd Then
 ' Yes, 19:45 is between  6:30 and 22:00 '
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you should be using dates to store the values.  Then it's a simple matter of checking the time components. Note that the implementation below is inclusive (i.e. if the time is exactly the start or end time, it will print the message.

```
    Dim dateToCheck As Date = Date.Parse("2014/08/15 19:45")

    ' The date portion doesn't matter, so I'm just using 1/1/1970.
    Dim startTimeDate As Date = New Date(1970, 1, 1, 6, 30, 0)
    Dim endTimeDate As Date = New Date(1970, 1, 1, 22, 0, 0)

    Dim afterOrEqualToStartTime As Boolean = (dateToCheck.Hour >= startTimeDate.Hour) And (dateToCheck.Minute >= startTimeDate.Minute) And (dateToCheck.Second >= startTimeDate.Second)

    Dim beforeOrEqualToEndTime As Boolean = (dateToCheck.Hour <= endTimeDate.Hour) And (dateToCheck.Minute <= endTimeDate.Minute) And (dateToCheck.Second <= endTimeDate.Second)

    If (afterOrEqualToStartTime And beforeOrEqualToEndTime) Then
        MsgBox("Date is between the start and end times")
    End If
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 Dim str As String = "2014/08/15 19:45"
 Dim time As DateTime = DateTime.Parse(str)

'here get the hour and minutes, and now you can compare with the others
 Dim tmpTime As DateTime = time.ToString("t")
```

Answer (score 0):

Comparing time is difficult using Date variables.

Using a data difference, with a tolerance, is one way to deal with binary time.

I use strings:

```
    Dim dt As Date = "2014/08/15 22:45"
    Dim s As String = dt.ToString("H:MM")
    If s > "06:30" And s <= "22:00" Then
        MsgBox("yes")
    Else
        MsgBox("no")
    End If
```

note the leading 0 in 06:30 in the sample.