# How to calculate time difference between two times in vb

Tags: vb.net

I need to calculate time difference between two time
The shift Start time is 04:30:Pm to 12:30AM
The Employee IN time is 08:30 AM then it shows the error message time expired

What I have tried:

```
dtShifTime = Convert.ToDateTime("16:30").ToString("HH:mm")
Dim dtEntryTime As DateTime = Convert.ToDateTime("08:30").ToString("HH:mm")
If lblStartTime.Text <> "" And (dtLateTime < dtEntryTime) Then
MBox("Time Expired")
End IF
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get time difference between two timespan in vb.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18895045/get-time-difference-between-two-timespan-in-vb-net)

Answer (score 0):

By calling ToString you convert the DateTime object into a String. And then you save it into a DateTime variable.

I don't know what you're trying to do, but to get the difference between two times you just subtract them.

```
Dim dtStart As DateTime = new DateTime(year:= 1, month := 1, day:= 1, hour:= 8, minute:= 30, second := 0)
Dim dtEnd As DateTime = new DateTime(year:= 1, month := 1, day:= 1, hour:= 20, minute:= 0, second := 0)
Dim tsDiff As TimeSpan = dtEnd - dtStart
Console.WriteLine(tsDiff.ToString())
```

I recommend you read the documentation for what you're trying to use.
[DateTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime?view=netframework-4.7.2) and [TimeSpan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan?view=netframework-4.7.2).

Instead of the constructor you can [parse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime?view=netframework-4.7.2#parsing-02) with DateTime.Parse(), ParseExact or TryParse if you definitely need to use a string as an input, which you should avoid if possible.

Aside from that you should do some basic searching and researching. For example this comes up as the first hit: [Get time difference between two timespan in vb.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18895045/get-time-difference-between-two-timespan-in-vb-net) when searching "time difference vb.net"